# jQuery file upload code and callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, callback

I have an issue that I've been stuck on for a while and would really appreciate your help. I have the examples running and when I try to incorporate the code into my site I notice that some features are not working because i am not receiving a callback from jquery.fileupload.js. So my file is testBasic.html and is located in the www/fileupload directory where I installed the jQuery fileupload source code. Now when I move testBasic.html file up a directory to www (and change the js paths in the source code) I notice that the add callback is not working correctly. The logic in the add callback is executed but my callback handler code is never executed so the file names are not output to the screen.

This is the code that is not executed :

```
 done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
        });
    },
```

I have tested this a number of times, all the js paths look good in both files but for some reason the callback handler code is never executed if the file is not in the fileupload directory. Any ideas? Or how can I go about debugging this. I am using firebug currently. Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards
Shane

Comment: can you give your folder / path structure as well as html code and js code.?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Additional error handling would have helped. The root cause was an incorrect path passed to a function which caused an error.